# Displaying dialog box (via alert or sweetalert) scrolls to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sweetalert

I have a long table (ex: 1000 rows). Each row has a button on it, that, if pressed, displays a sweetalert dialog via jQuery. (http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

PROBLEM: If I scroll down, let's say to 50% of the table, when I click the button the dialog does appear correctly, BUT, the table has scrolled all the way to the top of the page. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the css position of how sweetalert is displayed. I tried changing it from fixed to absolute, but it doesn't work.

```
.sweet-overlay, .sweet-alert{
    position: absolute !important;
    }
```

Using javascript "alert", instead of sweetalert, has the same effect. If I add "e.preventDefault();" then it works for alert, but not sweetalert.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post an example snippet, fiddle, etc.?

Comment: I guess the button is type of <a href="#">, is it? If so, clicking on it will navigate to #, which is basically the top of the page. You need to cancel the default behaviour either by returning false or calling e.preventDefault() in the handler function. Or, try using <button type="button">instead of <a>

Answer (score 1):

The original sweet alert plugin is unsupported, I suggest you using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) plugin, which doesn't have the issue you mentioned.

Migration is simple, here's the migration guide: [Migration from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

Here's the example of your case (100 rows) implemented with SweetAlert2:

```js
swal({
  html: '<table>' + '<tr><td>row</td></tr>'.repeat(100) + '</table>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @limonte I'll check it out. The issue I'm having though is not a table within the dialog. The long table is on the page itself. So, if I scroll down the table, when the dialog appears it scrolls to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it.

There's a CSS issue that MAY affect some users. Sweet Alert 1 and 2 both write a javascript when a modal opens, that adds a class to your

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

It may work for some users to simply remove this CSS, strangely, it didn't for me.

So comment out line 699 in sweet-alert.js

```
// addClass(document.body, swalClasses.shown); // BREAKS THEME
```

Update:

You CAN just add some css:

```
body.swal2-shown { overflow-y: none !important; }
```

However, I get a strange bar. But I'm doing some strange theme stuff. This is the less of two evils. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the JS i can see that the legacy version of sweet alert plugin adds a style called stop-scrolling to document body on call. This seems to be what effects the position on the page.

As a quick fix on a site i was working on, commenting out the height and overflow on this style (in sweetalert.css) stopped the page jumping.

Obviously not a final solution, just a fix.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You were close, see my answer